# Splash screen duration does not change

Tags: ionic-framework, visual-studio-cordova

I have an Apache Cordova project using VS2015 and am using the Ionic framework.

My config.xml includes the following:

```
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
```

However I only see the splash screen for a very brief duration (maybe 1/2 a second) when deploying to an iOS device.

Is there some other implementation that is required for splash screens to appear for the time specified by 'SplashScreenDelay'?

Answer (score 0):

Have u tried in in an emulator it might me a one off issue with the device.I would recoment using the GennyMotion emulator.

If you are setting up the splash screen using the cli i would recommend this tutorial and video here

http://pointdeveloper.com/how-to-add-splash-screen-for-ionic-framework-apps/

Comment: I have been using Ripple simulator however the splash screen does not appear here at all, and on the device appears for only half a second.

Comment: i have seen it that for no reason some bug appear try to build by creating a new project then add your html files in it